# SignalR not works on Google Chrome

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, google-chrome, signalr, signalr-hub

I have updated the signal R version from 1.1.3 to 2.1.2 in my project, but after updating it i found that implemented all functionality working proper on Firefox & Internet Explorer but not on Google Chrome. I'm already used long-polling & related solution but then also its not working, Actually Google Chrome is able to sends the update Signal's but not able to receive any signals from another browser.

Comment: I've just checked with SignalR **v2.1.2** and it is working with Chrome - I can send/receive to/from other browsers. Of course, my test was basic. Could you post more details?

Comment: Hi Aleksej Vasinov !!! 

After updating i just remove `RouteTable.Routes.MapHubs();` from `Application_Start()` method of Global.asax page & create a new Startup.cs page using the reference of following 
: http://www.asp.net/signalr/overview/releases/upgrading-signalr-1x-projects-to-20 & follows the same steps as per the given inside the link.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After updating Google Chrome with version 41.0.2266.2 canary, it's working properly.